# How to discover a Razor Class Library during the run time to load Razor Views?

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a Asp.net core app (v 2.1) with a set of controllers and models. They don't change. The app uses a Razor class library (RCL1) which has all the views.

I have another Razor Class library RCL2 which has more views which I need to load. This stackoverflow question [Loading Razor Class Libraries as plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50762385/loading-razor-class-libraries-as-plugins) has answer to load the DLLs at the start of the app.

Can I achieve this without starting the app? I just need to drop the RCL2 and the views from it will be picked up? The controller has logic to choose the right page from the parameter being passed in the route.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load ASP.NET Core Razor view dynamically at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48206993/how-to-load-asp-net-core-razor-view-dynamically-at-runtime)