# Dynamically include precompiled (Razor) views in .NET Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

**Idea**
I'm trying to build a modular .NET Core MVC application, were I can add 'modules' (extensions) just by copying the required libraries to a predefined folder. The application defines a set of dependencies (DI), error handling and basic layout; the modules provide the actual application or page logic.

We've build a proof of concept, using [ExtCore](http://extcore.net/) - the concept works great, Controllers are added automatically and the 'plain' Views are recognized easily (the ones set as 'Embedded Resource').

**Challenge**
However, I don't like the fact that Views are set to 'Embedded Resource', as it will be a small performance hit as the Razor page is now build at runtime.

**What we've tried**
As .NET Core 2.1 now has the ability to create [Reusable Razor UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio), I've created a  project with a reference to `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">` and compiled it to a Razor library (*.Views.dll).

When I link the Razor View library as project dependency in (main) application, everything works fine. However, the goal still is to make the application fully plug-and-play and allow libraries to be included just by deploying them to a folder.

I've tried to achieve this extending the Razor View Engine using a `PhysicalFileProvider`, but it won't recognize the views in the library.

```cs
 services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(opt =>
 {
     opt.FileProviders.Add(new PhysicalFileProvider("path/to/extension"));
 });
```

The result always is an exception telling me that `/Views/[controller]/[action].cshtml` is not found.

Searching other answers I came across [this](https://github.com/CodeFuller/stackoverflow/tree/Q49579800-Precompiled-Views-In-Library) project, which creates a `ViewLocationExpander`. I tried implementing various versions of this idea without luck - most likely because this is an older concept based on .NET Core 1.x which still uses a project dependency; although the Razor View engine now searches the namespace of the assembly.

```cs
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(opt =>
{
    opt.FileProviders.Add(new PhysicalFileProvider("path/to/extension");
    opt.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new DynamicLocationExpander());
});
```

Where `DynamicLocationExpander` looks like:

```cs
public class DynamicLocationExpander: IViewLocationExpander
{

    public DynamicLocationExpander()
    {

    }

    public void PopulateValues(ViewLocationExpanderContext context)
    {

    }

    public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context, IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
    {
        string assembly = ((ControllerActionDescriptor)context.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor)
            .ControllerTypeInfo.AsType().Assembly.GetName().Name;

        foreach (var viewLocation in viewLocations)
            yield return $"{assembly}/{viewLocation}";
    }
}
```

**Question**
How can we dynamically link a Razor View library, containing precompiled views, to the Razor Engine in a (parent) application?

Comment: I know, that I little late to party, but if you still need an answer, look at my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53954850/how-to-dynamically-load-pages-from-plugins-in-razor-pages-application

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load ASP.NET Core Razor view dynamically at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48206993/how-to-load-asp-net-core-razor-view-dynamically-at-runtime)