# How to dynamically load pages from plugins in Razor Pages application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm trying to deal with plugins using Razor Pages application.

Solution consists of 3 projects: one Razor Pages application and two Razor Class Libraries (RCL). Application **must not** refer RCL projects statically, they must be loaded as plugins:

[image]

There's nothing special inside pages. Feature pages just produce simple HTML. Index page builds a sort of menu.

Index page model:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public IEnumerable<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; private set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        MenuItems = new List<MenuItem>
        {
            new MenuItem { Route = "FeatureA", Title = "Feature A" },
            new MenuItem { Route = "FeatureB", Title = "Feature B" }
        };
    }
}
```

Index page:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
            @foreach (var item in Model.MenuItems)
            {
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/@item.Route">@item.Title</a>
                </li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I run the app, there are menu items, but their `href`s are empty:

```
<div class="text-center">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="">Feature A</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="">Feature B</a>
                </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Of course, all assemblies (app and feature ones) are in the same directory.

Menu works in two following cases:

- either if I refer RCL projects in App project, which kills plugins idea;
- or if I put `App.deps.json` with `FeatureLib_A` and `FeatureLib_B` as dependecies (just save deps file from first case, remove references, rebuild all, copy saved deps file).

Also, I've tried to eagerly load RCL assemblies in `Startup` class.
Assemblies are being loaded, but `Index` page behaves the same.

Is there any way to tell ASP infrastructure to use RCL assemblies without modifying deps file? What am I missing?

Answer (score 6):

I've figured it out.

The basic idea is to give `ApplicationPartManager` appropriate application parts.
It's important to note that:

- "code" assemblies (e.g. `FeatureLib_A.dll`) must be added as `AssemblyPart`;
- "view" assemblies (e.g. `FeatureLib_A.Views.dll`) must be added as `CompiledRazorAssemblyPart`.

Sample code:

```
public class Startup
{
    // ...

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var assemblyLoader = new DotNetCoreAssemblyLoader(searchPattern: "FeatureLib*.dll");

        services.AddMvc()
            .ConfigureApplicationPartManager(_ =>
            {
                foreach (var assembly in assemblyLoader.Assemblies)
                {
                    if (assembly.FullName.Contains("Views"))
                    {
                        _.ApplicationParts.Add(new CompiledRazorAssemblyPart(assembly));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _.ApplicationParts.Add(new AssemblyPart(assembly));
                    }
                }
            })
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }

    // ...
}
```

`DotNetCoreAssemblyLoader` is a custom class, which looks for assembly files using given search pattern, and loads assemblies via `AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath`.

Comment: Im trying to do this and I get "ileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Cool.Plugin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified."

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Startup
{

    public Startup( IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {

        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;



    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        services.AddMvc()
                      .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
                      .ConfigureApplicationPartManager(ConfigureApplicationParts); ;
    }



    private void ConfigureApplicationParts(ApplicationPartManager apm)
    {
        string rootPath = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath;
        var pluginsPath = Path.Combine(rootPath, "Plugins");

        var assemblyFiles = Directory.GetFiles(pluginsPath, "Plugin*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach (var assemblyFile in assemblyFiles)
        {
            try
            {
                var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyFile);
                if (assemblyFile.EndsWith(".Views.dll"))
                    apm.ApplicationParts.Add(new 
                           CompiledRazorAssemblyPart(assembly));
                else
                    apm.ApplicationParts.Add(new AssemblyPart(assembly));
            }
            catch (Exception e) { }
        }
    }
}
```